# display grid view with different height -- HTML

Tags: html, css, gridview, gallery

I want to display images as grid view in an HTML document. Here is the sample image, what an looking for.

[image]

I want different height for my li tag. Now my HTML takes same height for all li tag .

This is my html

```
<div class="blog_main_midd_section"><ul>
                 <li>
                     <div class="blog_images">
                         <img src="images/blog_img01.png" alt="">

                        </div>
                    </li>
                 <li>
                     <div class="blog_images">
                         <img src="images/blog_img02.png" alt="">

                        </div>
                    </li>

                 <li>
                     <div class="blog_images">
                         <img src="images/blog_img03.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>

                 <li>
                     <div class="blog_images">
                         <img src="images/blog_img04.png" alt="">

                        </div>
                    </li>

                 <li>
                     <div class="blog_images">
                         <img src="images/blog_img05.png" alt="">

                        </div>
                    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blog_main_midd_section {
 display:block;
}
.blog_main_midd_section ul {
 display:block;
 margin:0 0 75px 0;
}

.blog_main_midd_section ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 border:1px solid #50565a;
 width:31%;
 padding:0 0 20px 0;
 height:auto;
 margin:15px 1%;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

can anyone please advice me how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To display elements on your page as a grid view you can use one of existing jquery plugins which work as a charm and with nice animations. You can find one which suits your need [in this post](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-grid-plugin/) or just search for "*jquery plugin grid*".